# Extract text from webpage using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

How could i use python selenium to extract  "`: Sahih al-Bukhari 248`"

the following does not seem to work

```
reference = find_element_by_xpath(".//div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]").text
print reference
```

**see html code below**

```
 <div class="actualHadithContainer">
    <!-- Begin hadith -->
    <a name="1"></a>
    <div class="englishcontainer">
    <div class="english_hadith_full" style="display: block;">
    <div class="hadith_narrated"><p>Narrated `Aisha:</p></div>
    <div class="text_details">
    <p>Whenever the Prophet (ﷺ) took a bath after Janaba he started by washing his hands and then performed ablution like that for the prayer. After that he would put his fingers in water and move the roots of his hair with them, and then pour three handfuls of water over his head and then pour water all over his body.</p></div>
    <div class="clear"></div></div></div>
    <div class="arabic_hadith_full arabic"><span class="arabic_sanad arabic"></span>
    <span class="arabic_text_details arabic">حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ يُوسُفَ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنَا مَالِ</span><span class="arabic_sanad arabic"></span></div>
    <!-- End hadith -->
    <div class="bottomItems">
    <table class="hadith_reference" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody><tr><td><b>Reference</b></td>
    <td>&nbsp;:&nbsp;Sahih al-Bukhari 248</td></tr>
    <tr><td>In-book reference</td>
    <td>&nbsp;:&nbsp;Book 5, Hadith 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>USC-MSA web (English) reference</td><td>&nbsp;: Vol. 1, Book 5, Hadith 248</td></tr> 
    <tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i>(deprecated numbering scheme)</i></td></tr></tbody></table><div class="hadith_permalink"><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="reportHadith(2490, 'h102490')">Report Error</a> | <span class="sharelink" onclick="share('/bukhari/5/1')">Share</span></div></div>
    <div class="clear"></div></div>
```

I am using the code below to extract other items but having difficulties with the required excerpt above.

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import re
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get("https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/5");
print driver.title
print driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.book_page_english_name').text
print driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]').text

for person in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('actualHadithContainer'):
    try:
        title1 = person.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="hadith_narrated"]/p').text
        if title1:
            print title1
        else:
            print "exception"
            title1 = person.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="hadith_narrated"]').text
            print title1
        title2 = person.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="text_details"]/p').text
        if title2:
            print title2
        else:
            title2 = person.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="text_details"]').text
            print title2

        reference = find_element_by_xpath(".//div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]").text
        print reference

    except:
        print "exception"
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so, what does that say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using selenium API, you should perform some tasks like click a button or scroll to bottom.

When you need to extract information from HTML, you should use BeautifulSoup, it is much simple:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get("https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/5")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
soup.find(name='table', class_='hadith_reference').tr.text
```

And this page is static, you should use requests:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/5")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
for div in soup.find_all(class_='actualHadithContainer'):
    ref = div.find(name='table', class_='hadith_reference').tr.text
    print(ref)
```

out:

```
Reference : Sahih al-Bukhari 248
Reference : Sahih al-Bukhari 249
Reference : Sahih al-Bukhari 250
Reference : Sahih al-Bukhari 251
Reference : Sahih al-Bukhari 252
Reference : Sahih al-Bukhari 253
Reference : Sahih al-Bukhari 254
```